# Tried all suggested solutions, still doesn't show WhatsApp image preview for a link

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, whatsapp

I'm starting to grow desperate. I want to show a WhatsApp preview image for a link people can share. I tried everything I could find here or on Google. It STILL doesn't show up. This is is my current state of things:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="My Site" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is really My Site">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.my-site.com/subdir/" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" itemprop="image" content="https://www.my-site.com/subdir/ogthumb.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:alt" content="My Site Preview">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">   
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="256" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="256" /> 
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
```

Some of those headers are probably unnecessary, but I put all things together I found from different answers here or from external sources.

I also chose a low resolution (different max dimensions suggested in different sources, but this 256x256 should be fine according to all) as well as low image size (again, different max sizes suggested in different sources, but I got only 30kB and this should be fine according to all sources).

Please, kind people, can you show me what is still missing? My sanity thanks you.

Comment: This should be pretty easy to debug - Paste your URL [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and check for errors. Also it says [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) that _Use images that are at least 1080 pixels in width for best display on high resolution devices_ And your resolution is much less than that

Comment: Thank you Alon, I tried that already. Ironically,  1) this debugger is buggy and labels required fields as extraneous (got me the other day) and 2) it says my site is fine and even displays the thumbnail in the debugger evaluation result correctly! Also, it only recommends 1080px width but seems to require 600px. "At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 pixels in width to display image link ads" I already tried this as well though. Mind that this debugger is not WhatsApp specific, but rather fb.com targeted, although of course fb bought WhatsApp a while ago.

Comment: Alas, this does not illuminate the root cause.

Regarding debugger-bugs e.g. see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warnings-in-facebook-debugger/

Comment: Can you add the URL you're having problem with?

Comment: I would love to but it is private. I can provide all other infos though. It is a letsenrypt cert, might this be an issue? It shouldn't though should it, pretty standard nowadays.. What remaining factors might there be if nobody really knows a clearly defined set of required rules?